# How to group values on a distinct runID

Tags: azure, logging, query-string, azure-log-analytics

hi I'm trying to group some values related to a run Id by that run ID.

so what i have is:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where resource_workflowName_s =="RABE_REST_CARUS_V2"
| where resource_actionName_s  != "" 
   and resource_actionName_s == "Initialize_variable" 
   or resource_actionName_s == "Compose" 
   or resource_actionName_s == "RabeValidationCarusV2Test" 
   or resource_actionName_s == "HTTP"
| where status_s  == "Succeeded" 
| extend Duration = iff(isnotempty(endTime_t), todouble(endTime_t - startTime_t ) / 10000000, double(null))
| project RunId = resource_runId_s, Actions = resource_actionName_s , Duration
```

And i get this as a result:

[image]

what i want to to is sum the duration of the actions related to one RunID
what i have now is one action per runID and the duration of it...

Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where resource_workflowName_s =="RABE_REST_CARUS_V2"
| where resource_actionName_s != "" 
    and resource_actionName_s == "Initialize_variable" 
    or resource_actionName_s == "Compose" 
    or resource_actionName_s == "RabeValidationCarusV2Test" 
    or resource_actionName_s == "HTTP"
| where status_s  == "Succeeded" 
| extend Duration = iff(isnotempty(endTime_t), todouble(endTime_t - startTime_t ) / 10000000, double(null))
| project RunId = resource_runId_s, Actions = toobject(resource_actionName_s) , Duration
| summarize Actions = makeset(Actions), Durations = makeset(Duration), DurationSum = sum(Duration) by RunId 
| where DurationSum > 15
```